# Website not loading charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby

Everytime I try to run app.rb I get these errors

```
jquery.min.js:2 GET http://localhost:4567/water-level.json 404 (Not Found)
send    @   jquery.min.js:2
ajax    @   jquery.min.js:2
w.(anonymous function)  @   jquery.min.js:2
getJSON @   jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @   water-level-chart.js:59
l   @   jquery.min.js:2
c   @   jquery.min.js:2
setTimeout (async)      
(anonymous) @   jquery.min.js:2
u   @   jquery.min.js:2
fireWith    @   jquery.min.js:2
fire    @   jquery.min.js:2
u   @   jquery.min.js:2
fireWith    @   jquery.min.js:2
ready   @   jquery.min.js:2
_   @   jquery.min.js:2
```

not sure what this means.

here is my ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#action-form').submit(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting via the browser

    var form = $(this);

    $.ajax({

      type: form.attr('method'),

      url: form.attr('action'),

      data: form.serialize()

    }).done(function(data) {

      // Optionally alert the user of success here...

    }).fail(function(data) {

      // Optionally alert the user of an error here...
```

And here is my index.haml

```
%head
  %script{type: "text/javascript", src: url('/javascripts/jquery.min.js')}
  %script{type: "text/javascript", src: url('http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js')}
  %script{type: "text/javascript", src: url('/javascripts/highcharts-more.js')}
  %script{type: "text/javascript", src: url('/javascripts/solid-gauge.js')}
  %script{type: "text/javascript", src: url('/javascripts/synchronized-charts.js')}
  %script{type: "text/javascript", src: url('/javascripts/water-level-chart.js')}
  %script{type: "text/javascript", src: url('/javascripts/water-pump.js')}
  %link{rel: :stylesheet, type: :"text/css", href: url('/stylesheets/default.css')}
#container
  #synchronized
  .gauge
    #container-speed
    .pump-control
      %form{method: :post, action: '/take-action', id: 'action-form' }
        %input{type: 'hidden', name: 'action', value: 'start', id: 'action_input'}
        %span{id: 'pumper', onclick: 'takeAction()'}
          start
```

I've never worked with javascript or jquery. I'm trying to follow this project https://www.hackster.io/demirhanaydin/waterpi-houseplant-remote-watering-and-monitoring-system-340400#toc-step-1--setup-dynamodb-0 and I'm on step 6 just can't figure it out.

Comment: So, the file water-level.json sounds like something that should be generated by your raspberry pi, but it doesn't exist.  Did the tests at the end of step 5 work properly?

Comment: @James yes all the test work.

Comment: Try the url http://localhost:4567/water-level.json in a browser.  If you get "not found" then there would seem to be a problem between the script that generates the json from the route request (ie [app.rb](https://github.com/demirhanaydin/waterpi-web/blob/master/app.rb)) and the database, maybe double check the config in [boot.rb](https://github.com/demirhanaydin/waterpi-web/blob/master/boot.rb)